# Bind a PHP form button to a javascript method

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Hi guy I'm new to php and I have a php form as shown below, it used to work before I applied bootstrap to it.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Login Page</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link type="text/css" href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">       
    </head>
    <body> 
        <!-- Main Container -->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                        <h1 class="text-center login-title">Sign in to HRMS</h1>
                        <div class="account-wall">
                            <img class="profile-img" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-b0-k99FZlyE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/eu7opA4byxI/photo.jpg?sz=120"
                                alt="">
                            <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="">
                                <input type="text" id="txtEmpID" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee ID" required autofocus>
                                <input type="password" id="txtEmpPass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                                <button id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>                  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var login_url =  "<?php echo Util::convertLink("Login") ; ?>" ;
            <?php include (PATH_CODE . "js/general/login.min.js") ; ?>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

with the button Login bind to a method in login.js

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $('#btnLogin').button().bind('click',this,onLogin) ;
}) ;

function onLogin(obj) {             
    alert( $('#txtEmpID').val());
}
```

it there something i'm missing?

Comment: First, var login_url =  "<?php echo Util::convertLink('Login') ; ?>"; Try with $('#btnLogin').click(function(){alert($('#txtEmpID').val()); return false;});

Comment: It seems like your form has no action="" -> so when you submit, it does nothing. Point it to your login-script to parse the information from the formdata.

Comment: What does it do? Does it alert? Did you include jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $('#btnLogin').bind({
      click: function() {
        onLogin(this);
      }
    });
});

function onLogin(obj) {             
    alert( $('#txtEmpID').val());
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NJY5a/)